# How can I match entries in pandas dataframes using multiple criteria and fuzzy logic?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, string-matching

Thank you for your help. I believe that this is a common problem, but I'm unable to find a solution on SO that addresses this partiuclar form of it. I'm a newer programmer and deeply appreciative of any assistance.

I have two sets of data on healthcare companies. Data in `df1` is messy and contains null values, while data in `df2` is a lot more complete.

I need to match the companies in `df1` and `df2`, determine if there is a match, and if not a direct match, how close of a match it is. Both sets are of tens of thousands of companies and change/update daily, so I'm trying to build something that scales

Here is a reproducible program of what I've tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process

data1 = [['1001', 'Lutheran Family Hospital', 'Omaha', 'NE'],
         ['1020', 'Lutheran Family Hospital', 'Dallas', 'TX'],
         ['1021', 'Lutheran Regional Family Hospital', 'Des Plaines', 'IL'],
         ['1002', 'Independent Health', 'Fairbanks', 'AK'],
         ['1003', 'Lucky You Community Clinic', '', ''],
         ['1004', 'Belmont General Hospital', 'Belmont', 'CA'],
         ['1005', 'Louisiana Chiro', 'Lafayette', 'LA'],
         ['1006', 'Steven, Even', 'Chicago', 'IL'],
         ['1007', 'Kind Kare 4 Kids', 'New Mexico', 'New Mexico'],
         ['1008', 'Independence Mem', '', ''],
         ['1009', 'Gerald Griffin Health', 'Missoula', 'Montana'],
         ['1010', 'INTERNAL MED', 'CHARLESTON', 'SC'],
         ['1011', 'Belmont Hospital', '', ''],
         ['1012', 'Belmont Gnrl', 'Belmont', 'CA'],
         ['1013', 'St Mary Rehab', '', ''],
         ['1014', 'Saint Mary Med Center', 'Los Angeles', 'California'],
         ['1025', "St. Mary's Of Lourdes Regional Medical Center", 'Lincoln', 'NE'],
         ['1015', 'Bryan Bennington, MD', 'Huntsville', 'AL']]

data2 = [['1', 'Lutheran General Hospital', 'Fort Wayne', 'IN'],
         ['2', 'Lutheran Family Hospital', 'Omaha', 'NE'],
         ['3', 'Independence Memorial Health', 'Fairbanks', 'AK'],
         ['4', 'Lucky-You Community Clinic', 'New York', 'NY'],
         ['5', 'Belmont General Hospital', 'Belmont', 'CA'],
         ['6', 'Lafayette Joints R Us (DBA Louisiana Best Chiropractic)', 'Lafayette', 'LA'],
         ['7', 'Even Steven, MD', 'Chicago', 'IL'],
         ['8', 'Kind Kare 4 Kids, LLC Inc (FKA The Kindest Care)', 'Albequerque', 'NM'],
         ['9', 'The Best Doctor Group', 'Philadelphia', 'PA'],
         ['10', 'Internal Medical Group, PLLC', 'Charleston', 'SC'],
         ['11', "Saint Mary's Holy Name Rehabilitation", 'Lexington', 'KY'],
         ['12', 'St. Mary Regional Medical Center', 'Los Angeles', 'CA'],
         ['13', 'Advanced Outpatient Surgical Center', 'Seattle', 'WA']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['ID', 'Org_Name', 'City', 'State'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['ID', 'Org_Name', 'City', 'State'])

i = 0
scorethreshold = 80
df1["fuzzy"] = 0
for x in df1.Org_Name:
    noun,score,record = process.extractOne(x,df2.Org_Name)
    if score > scorethreshold:     
        df1.loc[i,'fuzzy'] = noun
    else:
        df1.loc[i,'fuzzy'] = None
    i = i + 1
```

The above produces the following result:

```
+----+------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|    |  ID  |                   Org_Name                    |    City     |   State    |                          fuzzy                          |
+----+------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|  0 | 1001 | Lutheran Family Hospital                      | Omaha       | NE         | Lutheran Family Hospital                                |
|  1 | 1020 | Lutheran Family Hospital                      | Dallas      | TX         | Lutheran Family Hospital                                |
|  2 | 1021 | Lutheran Regional Family Hospital             | Des Plaines | IL         | Lutheran Family Hospital                                |
|  3 | 1002 | Independent Health                            | Fairbanks   | AK         | Independence Memorial Health                            |
|  4 | 1003 | Lucky You Community Clinic                    |             |            | Lucky-You Community Clinic                              |
|  5 | 1004 | Belmont General Hospital                      | Belmont     | CA         | Belmont General Hospital                                |
|  6 | 1005 | Louisiana Chiro                               | Lafayette   | LA         | Lafayette Joints R Us (DBA Louisiana Best Chiropractic) |
|  7 | 1006 | Steven, Even                                  | Chicago     | IL         | Even Steven, MD                                         |
|  8 | 1007 | Kind Kare 4 Kids                              | New Mexico  | New Mexico | Kind Kare 4 Kids, LLC Inc (FKA The Kindest Care)        |
|  9 | 1008 | Independence Mem                              |             |            | Independence Memorial Health                            |
| 10 | 1009 | Gerald Griffin Health                         | Missoula    | Montana    |                                                         |
| 11 | 1010 | INTERNAL MED                                  | CHARLESTON  | SC         | Internal Medical Group, PLLC                            |
| 12 | 1011 | Belmont Hospital                              |             |            | Lutheran General Hospital                               |
| 13 | 1012 | Belmont Gnrl                                  | Belmont     | CA         | Belmont General Hospital                                |
| 14 | 1013 | St Mary Rehab                                 |             |            | Saint Mary's Holy Name Rehabilitation                   |
| 15 | 1014 | Saint Mary Med Center                         | Los Angeles | California | Saint Mary's Holy Name Rehabilitation                   |
| 16 | 1025 | St. Mary's Of Lourdes Regional Medical Center | Lincoln     | NE         | St. Mary Regional Medical Center                        |
| 17 | 1015 | Bryan Bennington, MD                          | Huntsville  | AL         |                                                         |
+----+------+-----------------------------------------------+-------------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, I'm trying to create something whereby I can determine whether not only company names match, but cities and states match too, and how closely all of this matches. I'm trying to create an output more like this, where `Fuzzy_ID` refers to the index location of the matching entry, and `Matched?` refers to a Boolean judgment:

```
+---+------+-----------------------------------+-------------+-------+----------+------------+----------+
|   |  ID  |             Org_Name              |    City     | State | Fuzzy_ID |   Score    | Matched? |
+---+------+-----------------------------------+-------------+-------+----------+------------+----------+
| 0 | 1001 | Lutheran Family Hospital          | Omaha       | NE    |        2 | 100        | YES      |
| 1 | 1020 | Lutheran Family Hospital          | Dallas      | TX    |        2 | some_score | NO       |
| 2 | 1021 | Lutheran Regional Family Hospital | Des Plaines | IL    |        2 | some_score | NO       |
| 3 | 1002 | Independent Health                | Fairbanks   | AK    |        3 | some_score | YES      |
| 4 | 1003 | Lucky You Community Clinic        |             |       |        4 | some_score | YES      |
+---+------+-----------------------------------+-------------+-------+----------+------------+----------+
```

How can this be accomplished? What methods exist that are better suited to what needs to be accomplished? Very grateful for any help provided.

Comment: How close is your data from the original? I mean, is it maybe that 99% of your companies are exact matches and the rest need fuzzy? then you probably could use merge to check for an exact match and filter out the rest and apply your fuzzy logic to it.

Comment: Maybe you could further improve the merge-hit-rate by converting everything to lowercase and cleansing actions like normalizing statenames.

Comment: Hello, thank you, I will implement the steps you advise!

Comment: What is *Fuzzy_ID* and what is the meaning of particular values (in the last table)?

Comment: @Valdi_Bo thank you, apologies for lack of clarity, the ```Fuzzy_ID``` is the index location of the corresponding possible match in ```df2```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is quite difficult and involves a number of steps, but at least
I attempt to lay out some general principles.

Start from tidying up the *state* column.
If somewhere there is full name of a state, replace it with state code.

Maybe you should also take some time to clarify "No state" cases in *df1*,
as another step to clean the data.

Then, for each *row* in *df1*, attempt to find the best matching row in *df2*.
To do it, use the following procedure:

1. Using *process.extract*, find in *df2* a pool of best matches, by *name*,
   with the current *row*, assuming some values for *limit* and *score_cutoff*.
   If *row* contains *state*, check in *df2* only rows from this state.
   Save match ratio for each match found as *name_ratio*.
2. For each item from the above pool, compute *WRatio* on *city* column,
   saving it as *city_ratio*.
3. Use some aggregation formula, to compute *total_ratio* for each match
   from *name_ratio* and *city_ratio*.
   I'm also not sure how this formula should be.
4. Take the match with maximal *total_ratio*, but if this (best) ratio
   is below some *total_ratio_cutoff*, assume that the current *row* has **no match**.

Of course, it remains to you to experiment with values of particular
parameters and look how changes in their values affect the final result.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me out a lot in terms of an order of processes to implement, I will try to follow.